# MySQL and jpg pictures in BLOB

Tags: mysql, jpeg

I have to write jpg picture into database BLOB field. By hand via one command. On Windows via my client (Navicat) everything is ok but on linux (Ubuntu) can't do it.
Comand is simple:

```
UPDATE table SET field = LOAD_FILE("/tmp/picture.jpg") WHERE id = 40
```

I try to do it as a linux (the same client Navicat) root user (sudo) and in the database user is also root without password. All privileges (including FILE) are set for root in MySQL.

Where I make an error?

Comment: on linux are the files actually being uploaded to `/tmp` folder, or is it in a different absolute path?

Comment: Pls share the exact error message with us!

Comment: Can't load file from any place, any folder. And no error is displayed by MySQL client.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's clear Ubuntu and MySQL 5.x had such an error. After I updated system and the database this LOAD_FILE is working properly.